# Sms reader receiver not working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sms

I am try to read incoming sms that I sent to the user.
I saw a lots of answers around the internet but I can't make it work.

This is my manifest with the permissions and the Receiver:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<application>
...
<receiver android:name=".notifications.receiver.SmsCodeReader"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

And this is my Receiver class:

```
public class SmsCodeReader extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "received something", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

I am working on API 22 so no need run-time permission, but no matter what I try I cant make the Receiver to work. 
I didn't get any exception or error in the log

EDIT:
If I send Broadcast with Intent like this:

```
Intent in = new Intent("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
sendBroadcast(in);
```

I can see the Toast. so it's mean the Broadcast is properly registered in the manifest.
So, why it doesn't work with real SMS?

Thanks to all

Comment: Do you have the permissions outside of the `<application>` tags, and the `<receiver>` inside them? Are you sure the `name` attribute on the `<receiver>` is pointing to the right class, in the right place? Are you launching an `Activity` in your app at least once after installation to bring it out of the _stopped_ state? Does the device have any additional settings or permissions beyond the standard Android ones that might be preventing your app from receiving SMS by default?

Comment: The manifest is right, no error in it.
I did have a default SMS app in my device

Comment: pleas see my edit... Thanks

Comment: Ok. It's just because I have a Xioami not 2. I needed to give the permission to read SMS in the app settings